# Log access by users in Django?

Tags: django, authentication, logging

Currently I have the HTTP logs that show me what page has been accessed, but they do not include username. What would be the easiest way to extract that information? A middleware?

Comment: It did, thanks - that's exactly what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to create a [custom middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/):

```
class RequestLoggingMiddleware(object):
    def process_response(self, request, response):
        if request.user and not request.user.is_anonymous():
            # log message here
        return response
```

Another option is to use [`sentry`](https://www.getsentry.com) centralized logging tool that is easy to setup and it provides a very nice logging user interface. Log messages are full of versatile information including user associated with the request.